# Lorentz transformation of 4-velocity to an instantaneous rest frame

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

In this question I'll use natural units ($c=1$) and the metric signature $(-+++$).

Say we have a particle on a worldline with a four-velocity at a particular instant of $v^\mu=(v^0, v^1, 0, 0)$ in frame $S$. We can do a Lorentz transformation to be in a frame $S'$ where $v'^\mu=(v'^0, 0, 0, 0)$, by boosting in the $x^1$ direction by speed $u=v^1$.

This is represented by the boost matrix

$${\Lambda^\mu}_\nu = \begin{pmatrix}\gamma & -u\gamma & 0 & 0\\-u\gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

But if I explicitly carry out the boost, I get

$$v'^0=\gamma(v^0-uv^1)=\frac{v^0-(v^1)^2}{\sqrt{1-(v^1)^2}}$$
$$v'^1=\gamma(v^1-uv^0)=\frac{v^1(1-v^0)}{\sqrt{1-(v^1)^2}}$$

We know that we should get $v'^0=1$ and $v'^1=0$ (because $v^\mu v_\mu =v'^\mu v'_\mu=-1$). But I can't see how this is consistent with the two equations above. So what have I done wrong?

Comment: I think the spacial components of the 4-velocity are nit directly the velocity but related by a factor of gamma.

Comment: @lalala Ah yes, I've just realised that $v^\mu=dx^\mu/d\tau=\gamma(1, dx^i/dt)$. But I'm struggling to understand what this means right now

Comment: @lalala Ohhh, I think you have to boost by $u=v^1/\gamma$, not merely $v^1$, because in $S$, the particle is moving at $v^1/\gamma=dx^1/dt$ at that instant

Answer (score 3):

So, as user lalala pointed out, I didn't take enough care with the definition of 4-velocity.

$$v^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$$

where $\tau$ is proper time for the particle. However, in $S$, this is

$$v^\mu=(\frac{dx^0}{d\tau}, \frac{dx^i}{d\tau})
\\=(\frac{dt}{d\tau}, \frac{dt}{d\tau}\frac{dx^i}{dt})
\\=\gamma (1, \frac{dx^i}{dt})$$

as $t=x^0$ and $\gamma = \frac{dt}{d\tau}$.

The crucial point I missed is that the particle is moving with speed $\frac{dx^1}{dt}=\frac{v^1}{\gamma}$ in $S$. Thus, we need to boost by $u=\frac{v^1}{\gamma}$, **not** $v^1$.

Thus the correct expressions for the boosted 4-velocity components are

$$v'^0=\gamma v^0 - (v^1)^2
\\v'^1=\gamma v^1 - v^1 v^0$$

As $\gamma=v^0$, it follows that $v'^0=1$ and $v'^1=0$ as required.